# Random Sequence Generator in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mobile, random

I want to build a sequence randomiser mobile app in c#. I would like to retrieve the smallest and the largest number in an interval from two diffrent text boxes, and after I click the Generate button to display the random sequence of all the numbers in a new text box.

My code only displays one number. What's wrong with it?

Thanks.

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
       this.InitializeComponent();           
    }
   private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int seed = 345;
        var result = "";
        int min = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text);
        int max = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
       Random r3 = new Random(seed);
        for (int i = min; i < max; i++)
        {
            ecran.Text = (/*"," + r3.Next(min, max)*/i).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you assign sequence values to `ecran.Text` in a loop. Instead, you should create a string representation of the sequence, and assign it at the end.

Use [`Shuffle<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262619/335858) method from this Q&A:

```
int min = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text);
int max = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
if (max < min) return;
var sequence = Enumerable.Range(min, max-min+1).ToList();
Shuffle(sequence);
ecran.Text = string.Join(",", sequence);
```

Comment: your solution does not allow numbers to duplicate. Maybe it would better to use something like this: `var sequence = Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1).Select(i => r3.Next(min, max));`?

Comment: @AleksAndreev From OP's incorrect code it appears that he wants a "random sequence of all the numbers" in the min-max range. Otherwise, a single count would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to make it work. It underlines in red Shuffle and Jon.

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight Yes. That's what I really want.

Comment: @SilviuIsidor You need to copy `Shuffle<T>` from the Q&A that I linked to the question.

Comment: @SilviuIsidor Did you follow the link?

Comment: So I used this `public static IList<T> NextList<T>(this Random r, IEnumerable<T> source)
        {var list = new List<T>();
            foreach (var item in source)
            { var i = r.Next(list.Count + 1);
                if (i == list.Count) { list.Add(item);}
                else
                {
                    var temp = list[i];
                    list[i] = item;
                    list.Add(temp);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }` How do I make `ecran.Text` display the list?

Comment: @SilviuIsidor See the assignment on the last line of my answer.

Comment: @Aleks Andreev Your solutions does not generate random sequence but a random list of numbers. The problem is that I get the same numbers twice or many times. I want a shuffled list.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight This worked: `/* generate the sequence */
            Random rnd = new Random();
            var sequence = Enumerable.Range(min, max).OrderBy(n => rnd.Next());

            /* write down the sequence */
            ecran.Text = string.Join(",", sequence);`

Answer (score 4):

To clarify what was wrong with your solution:

Inside the loop you were constantly reassigning the value of ecran.Text.

i.e.

```
1st loop cycle      > ecran.Text = ", " + 77
2nd loop cycle      > ecran.Text = ", " + 89

//Value of ecran.Text after 1st cycle is ", 77"
//Value of ecran.Text after 2nd cycle is ", 89"
```

Overriding the value of ecran.Text with each iteration.

Fixed by adding a plus symbol in front of equals `ecran.Text += ", " + LOGIC`